# Normalize table variables grouped by the first column value

Tags: matlab

I have the following table(8 rows);

```
   Name       Age    Height    Weight    
__________    ___    ______    ______    

'Smith4'       30     71        176            
'Smith6'       80     69        163            
'Smith1'       10     64        131             
'Smith4'       40     67        133            
'James9'       49     64        119             
'James5'       56     45         56            
'James5'       87     56        890             
'James5'       23     56         43
```

Here, each of the 4 rows is a group. I want to normalize the age of each group. Such as, the minimum age of 'Smith' would be point to 1 and the maximum age of 'Smith' would point to 100 (and rest would be based on max and min). The same thing i wanna do it with James. 
does anyone know how i can loop it in MATLAB? can anyone write me the code?

My Original data:

```
     name                value 
______________________    ______________  

'kiemo_250'           1.3586
'kiemo_298-10M'       0.35857
'kiemo_298-12M'       0.48857
'kiemo_298-16M'       0.70429
'kiemo_298-24M'       0.97857
'kiemo_298-32M'       1.0429
'kiemo_298-5M'        0.012857
'kiemo_298-8M'        0.17857
'neywork_250'         1.01
'neywork_298-12M'     0.69714
'neywork_298-18M'     0.76286
'neywork_298-1M'      0.0057143
'neywork_298-3M'      0.29429
'neywork_298-5M'      0.47857
'neywork_298-6M'      0.54286
'neywork_298-8M'      0.61429
'man-10M'             0.58286
'man-14M'             0.56571
'man-18M'             0.51857
'man-24M'             0.55714
'man-30M'             0.51143
'man-4M'              0.39714
'man-8M'              0.52143
'man'                 0.40857
  ""                    ""
  ""                    "" 
  ""                    ""  
  ""                    ""
```

Comment: Do you names actually end in a number like that?

Comment: i have added a part of my original data. 
With each group(8 rows) i want to normalize the minimum to 1 and maximum to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's construct the table

```
t = table({'Smith4'; 'Smith6'; 'Smith1'; 'Smith4'; 'James1'; 'James5'; 'James5'; 'James5'}, [30 80 10 40 49 56 87 23]', 'VariableNames', {'Name', 'Age'})

%     Name      Age
%   ________    ___
%
%   'Smith4'    30 
%   'Smith6'    80 
%   'Smith1'    10 
%   'Smith4'    40 
%   'James1'    49 
%   'James5'    56 
%   'James5'    87 
%   'James5'    23
```

You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to determine the leading last name.

```
lastname = regexp(t.Name, '^[A-Za-z]*', 'match', 'once');

%   'Smith'    'Smith'    'Smith'    'Smith'    'James'    'James'    'James'    'James'
```

Then use the third output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to assign a unique ID to each unique last name

```
[~, ~, ind] = unique(lastname, 'stable');

%    1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2
```

Then you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to normalize each group

```
normalized = accumarray(ind, t.Age, [], @(x){(x - min(x)) ./ (max(x) - min(x))});

%   [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

Then we can flatten `normalized` using `cat`, multiply by 100 to get your values between `0` and `100`, and then replace `t.Age`

```
t.Age = cat(1, normalized{:}) * 100;

%     Name       Age  
%   ________    ______
%
%   'Smith4'    28.571
%   'Smith6'       100
%   'Smith1'         0
%   'James1'    40.625
%   'James5'    51.562
%   'James5'       100
%   'James5'         0
```

**Update**

If instead you want your normalized values to be within a certain range (1 -- 5), you would do the following.

```
lower = 1;
upper = 5;

normalized = accumarray(ind, t.Age, [], @(x){((x - min(x)) ./ (max(x) - min(x))) * (upper-lower) + lower});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. code: `normalized = splitapply(@(x){(x - min(x)) ./ (max(x) - min(x))}, t.Age, ind);` does not work, it says: Undefined function or variable 'splitapply'

Comment: @Hasan Updated to use `accumarray` since you don't seem to be using R2015b

Comment: What if i want to normalize it between 1 to 5? (the min age=1 and max age=5)? and rest accordingly.

Comment: Dear Suever, I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168628/matlab-vactor-table-to-normal-table-extraction

Can you please check it