# Matlab vactor table to normal table extraction

Tags: matlab, math

I have a table name `output` which contains the dimention like this:

`cat          values        s1            s2     sub_cat
 1          [1x2 double]    0.66584    3.1383    {2x1 cell}`

values are such as:
`cat         values               s1      s2      sub_cat

1          2.5  3.4            0.555    3.999    emozi-1
                                                 emozi-3
2          2.9  7.1            5.0       2       khazal-11
                                                 kha-9`

How can i re-arrange this table like this(remove vector to normal):

`cat       values        s1     s2      sub-cat
1         2.5          0.555   3.999   emozi-1 
1         3.4          0.555   3.999   emozi-3
2         2.9          5.0     2       khazal-11
2         7.1          5.0     2       kha-9`

Can anyone help to do this in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're after is a table [`stack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stack.html) operation. It's a bit tricky because I think you're trying to stack two table variables simultaneously (without getting all the combinations), so here's what I think you need:

```
%# Sample table data
t = table([1;2], [1, 2; 3, 4], [0.1; 0.2], {'a', 'b'; 'c', 'd'}, ...
    'VariableNames', {'cat', 'values', 's1', 'sub_cat'});
%# Combine corresponding columns of 'values' and 'sub_cat' so
%# that we've got something we can stack
t2 = table(t.cat, [num2cell(t.values(:,1)), t.sub_cat(:,1)], ...
    [num2cell(t.values(:,2)), t.sub_cat(:,2)], ...
    t.s1, 'VariableNames', {'cat', 'vs1', 'vs2', 's1'});
%# Actually call 'stack'
t3 = stack(t2, {'vs1', 'vs2'});
%# Unpick the variables in 't3' into something more useful
t4 = table(t3.cat, t3.s1, cell2mat(t3.vs1_vs2(:,1)), ...
    t3.vs1_vs2(:,2), 'VariableNames', ...
    {'cat', 's1', 'values', 'sub_cat'})
```

Comment: i want he sub-cat to be {2x1 cell}

Comment: In that case, you can simplify the above code so that you simply make two variables from the columns of `values`, and call `stack` based on that.